# Reset custom hook to initial state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've created a custom Hook that detects if a click was done outside of a component:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useOutsideClick = (ref) => {
    
    const [clickOutside, setClickOutside] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        
        const handleClick = (e) => {
            
            ref.current?.contains(e.target)
            ? setClickOutside(false)
            : setClickOutside(true);   
            
        };
      
        document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
        
        return () => document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
      
    }, [ref]);
    
    return clickOutside;
    
};

export default useOutsideClick;
```

I'm using the Hook on a main component. After the user clicks outside the component, the Hook needs to reset to its initial state (`outsideClick = false`):

```js
const App = () => {
    
    const [activeComponent, setActiveComponent] = useState(null);
    const dropDownRef                           = useRef();
    const outsideClick                          = useOutsideClick(dropDownRef);
    
    useEffect( () => {
        
        if(outsideClick){
            
            setActiveComponent('WhatAreYouWorkingOn');  
            
            // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            // At this point, outsideClick needs to be false again
            // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   
            
        }
        
    }, [outsideClick, setActiveComponent]);
    
    return (
        <div className = 'DropDown' ref = {dropDownRef}/>
    );
}

export default App;
```

How can I reset `useOutsideClick` to its initial state?

Comment: Why not `setOutsideClick` imported from your `useOutsideClick` hook and run it after `setActiveComponent`

Comment: as @iamcastelli said, just const [outsideClick, setOutsideClick] = useOutsideClick(...) and use your setOutsideClick to set it to false. Inside useOutsideClick return [outsideClick, setOutsideClick]